# How to remove access to all files or attachments from a user

Tags: attachment, files, access, global-search

Just like I can remove access to a particular object, how can I remove the user's access to Files or Attachments? Right now they can still access it if they use the global search function. I think there is no way to disable the global search function too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Who Can See My File?**

Your files in Salesforce can be private to you, privately shared, or visible to your entire company. Learn how to identify a file’s sharing settings and how to change them. Check this [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_settings_perms.htm&type=5) for details

**Make a File Private**

You can restrict access to shared files that you own by making them private.Details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_make_private.htm&type=5)

Steps

> - From the file detail page, click either Share File Share File | Sharing Settings or Show All on the Shared With list.
> - In the Sharing Settings dialog box, click Make private (or Restrict access if the file originated in a Salesforce CRM Content library).
> - In the confirmation dialog box, click Make private (or Restrict access).

**View Where a File Is Shared**

Find out who can see a file and their level of access. From the File Detail page, you can access a full list of every person or object the file is shared with.

The Shared With list on a file detail page shows you who the file is shared with and their level of access. Check details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_shared_with.htm&type=5)

**Global Search**

Yes, unfortunately global search can't be disable for particular user or profile. Check this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l31zAAA)